# virt-install Couldn't find hvm kernel for Ubuntu tree

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, iso, virt-install, hvm

I'm trying to create a VM using KVM and virt-installer. When i use virt-install I get the following error:

Starting install...
Retrieving file .treeinfo...                                                                                                          |    0 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file content...                                                                                                            |    0 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file info...                                                                                                               |   63 B  00:00:00
ERROR    Couldn't find hvm kernel for Ubuntu tree.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start test
otherwise, please restart your installation.

This is my virt-install command:

virt-install \ 
--name test \ 
 
--ram 16384 \ 
--location="./images/ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso" \ 
--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/kaleb.qcow2,bus=virtio,size=100 \ 
--vcpus 4 \ 
--graphics none \ 
--os-variant=ubuntu18.04 \ 
--network bridge=test \ 
-x "console=ttyS0"

I saw in here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116383/couldnt-find-hvm-kernel-for-ubuntu-tree to switch from location arg to cdrom, but I need the extra-args to forward the console to tty. Any help please?

Comment: I'm currently running into the exact same thing. Were you able to find a workaround for this?

Comment: Ok, so the solution for me was to use the "legacy" server image as described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1274468/184483

Answer (score 0):

You should append this to location `kernel=casper/vmlinuz,initrd=casper/initrd`

Your `virt-install` command would be

```
virt-install \
--name test \
--ram 16384 \
--location="./images/ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso,kernel=casper/vmlinuz,initrd=casper/initrd" \
--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/kaleb.qcow2,bus=virtio,size=100 \
--vcpus 4 \
--graphics none \
--os-variant=ubuntu18.04 \
--network bridge=test \
-x "console=ttyS0"
```